# Application Insights - Global Minimum Severity Level Filter?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-application-insights

Is there a single place where I can set the minimum severity for log writing? it should apply also to the traces written via `TelemetryClient.TraceTelemetry` also! there are several question covering only `ILogger`...

Comment: what's your project? .net or .net core? web or console project?

Comment: @IvanYang .net core, 3.1, latest SDK, both console and web

Comment: Just confirm, do you actually mean log level? like just capture the log level like information or trace or exception?

Comment: I mean `SeverityLevel`. Say that I don't want to register Verboses logs anymore, only warnings and up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way. But you can use [telemetry processor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#create-a-telemetry-processor-c) to determine which `SeverityLevel` can be logged.

For example, create a class which implements ITelemetryProcessor, like below:

```
public class MyCustomFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
{
    private ITelemetryProcessor Next { get; set; }

    // next will point to the next TelemetryProcessor in the chain.
    public MyCustomFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
    {
        this.Next = next;
    }

    public void Process(ITelemetry item)
    {
        TraceTelemetry traceTelemetry = item as TraceTelemetry;

        if (traceTelemetry != null)
        {
            //use this line of code to determine which SeverityLevel should be logged. In this example, only SeverityLevel is warning and up can be logged
            if (traceTelemetry.SeverityLevel < SeverityLevel.Warning) { return; }
        }

        this.Next.Process(item);
    }
}
```

Then register it in Startup.cs(for .net core web app):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

        //register your custom TelemetryProcessor
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<MyCustomFilter>();
    }
```

Comment: I actually figured that `services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor` doesn't work all around, you have to use the `aiConfig.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder.Use(next => new SeverityLevelFilterTelemetryProcessor(next, config));`